# Should I keep an smtp connecton open between mails?

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

In my app, I need to send a confirmation e-mail to some customers every time some operation is finished.

How should I design, or what's best practice, the logic behind the smtp connection?

Should I connect authenticate the mail account and keep this connection open while the app is running (sometimes a couple of hours, with sometimes 20-30 minutes without any mail

Or should I close connection every time a mail is sent? Eventhough a mail can be sent multiple times a second on some operations...

I'm sending mails simply by telnetting to a remote webserver mail app.
This app can be used be multiple users at the same time using the same e-mail account.

So I need advice from people with experience in smtp behaviour and habits, How does a simple mail app works on this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may keep SMTP connections open for a few minutes.

e.g. Default Sendmail configuration caches 2 connections for up to  5 minutes when processing queued messages.  Sendmail issues `RSET` command to check cached connections before reuse.  Issuing `RSET` is a good way to reset SMTP session to known state.

Comment: it is event based, I was thinking on using the NOOP command on a timer every ? seconds to keep the session alive for as long as the app is running

Comment: You may issue 'RSET' command before reusing cached SMTP connection. If you get reply before some timeout then the connection may be reused.

Comment: ok, Ill watch for a 421 (timeout) code, If i Receive one, I simply flag connection as closed, If App needs to send email, I simple reconnect and unflag..